# Updating proxyAddresses using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We have an Office365 Tenant but no on-premises AD to sync from (yes, we run prevalently on linux). Our users "live" in an oracle database. From there they are replicated to all the other back-ends we use (OpenLDAP, MySQL, Kerberos, ... and now even Azure).

We are using "Microsoft Azure Client Libraries for Python" and are able to create and update users (we had to extend the class UserUpdateParameters).

But when it comes to update/set the users mail aliases (users have multiple local parts and perhaps more than one domain name part) we get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update.max_sgv.py", line 87, in <module>
    uu = graphrbac_client.users.update(object_id, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/graphrbac/operations/users_operations.py", line 275, in update
    raise models.GraphErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error.GraphErrorException: Property 'proxyAddresses' is read-only and cannot be set.
```

Has anybody an idea how to do this with python (azure, msrest)?

Btw: otherMails does not do the trick.

Anyhow, it'is not plausible to me to expose it to others APIs (for instance power shell AD extension) but not to the Graph API.

Thank you for your time and hopefully for your suggestions too.

Massimo Bassi

Comment: Could you post your code of do the update operation for user in `update.max_sgv.py` and the `parameters` value for the code `uu = graphrbac_client.users.update(object_id, parameters)`? Per my experience, it seems to be a property `proxyAddresses` exists in the `parameters` variable as request data. But according to the error information, the `proxyAddresses` is read-only and [only within the response body](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/f8dc98625404b75e5d6365ad30c04abc90ee751a/azure-mgmt/tests/recordings/test_graphrbac.test_graphrbac_users.yaml).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to set email address on User currently through Microsoft Graph API. We are currently investigating adding the needed support, but there is no ETA.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Well, i hope in an early arrival. Meanwhile, I will probably have to leave my comfort zone....