# Update O365 proxyAddresses via API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph API I need to be able to update the attribute `proxyAddresses` as part of our provisioning process to enable self-service password management for our end users.

I see that this attribute is read-only from the Graph API but as of 8 months ago MS was entertaining the possibility of making it RW. Does anyone have any color on this, has anyone found a workaround to this issue via API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating proxyAddresses using Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961856/updating-proxyaddresses-using-microsoft-graph-api)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported in either v1.0 or Beta at the moment but this is an open OverVoice request for this feature: [Ability to update the user's email aliases (proxyAddresses attribute)](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17449177-ability-to-update-the-user-s-email-aliases-proxya).

Comment: Thanks, one more place to complain . . .  :-), I added my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are working with bigger customers - usually you want to sync their identities from local Active Directory using AD Connect tool. In that case you should implement things and change proxyaddresses attribute in local AD, because it is the "identity authority" (means that you can't change it on cloud side and it must be done in on-prem AD).

So it could be workaround for problem you are trying to solve.

Also if it is cloud only (not synced) identity - you can use PowerShell to modify proxyaddresses attribute on users. 
Here is documentation on how to do that - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123794(v=exchg.160).aspx

Comment: We are the end user here, I am extending our on-boarding solution which is written purely in C#. All identities are cloud based only right now for a separate domain that does not exist on prem. I saw the PS route, but having built out authentication and custom classes to handle the provisioning and maintenance process, it seems silly to have to use powershell to change an attribute. I have opened a dev case with MS, I am thinking of setting an unused field during provisioning and write a cloud base server side process to move the attribute to the locked down proxyaddresses attribute.